# [FireFox][HTML5 FullScreen API] How can I detect whether user clicked 'allow' button and allow full-screen mode

Tags: html, firefox, fullscreen

I'm researching and using html5 full-screen API with FireFox, I have a local html file, name 'SamplePlayer.html'. If  I launched this file and clicked 'Full' button to make one element in to fullscreen mode like:

```
function launchFullScreen (element) {
  if (typeof(element) == "undefined")
    element = document.documentElement;
  if (element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } 
  else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
  else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
  return true;
}
```

FireFox shows a dialog(maybe something else)'Press ESC to exit fullscreen, allow fullscreen, allow, reject', my question is , How can I detect user click 'allow' button and this dialog disappear? not merely element come into full mode and the dialog still exist.

I' ve test with:

```
 document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', adjustElement, false); 
 document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', adjustElement, false); 
 document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', adjustElement, false); 

function adjustElement() {
   //alert("change");
   //var tmp = fullscreenElement();
   var tmp = fullscreen();
   alert(tmp);
 }

 function fullscreenElement() {
   return document.fullscreenElement ||
        document.webkitCurrentFullScreenElement ||
        document.mozFullScreenElement ||
        null;
 }

function fullscreen() {
   return document.fullscreen ||
        document.webkitIsFullScreen ||
        document.mozFullScreen ||
        false;
}
```

But while user request fullscreen, whether user clicked 'allow' button or not, all those function return true, how can I detect whether user clicked 'allow' button and allow full-screen mode with FireFox?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect if the "Allow" button was clicked, and you're not supposed to detect it or be able to detect it either. It is a user decision and implementation detail. 
Should there be some "hack" to detect it, it would be an implementation detail that is subject to change at any time, and there is a good chance it will change simply to close this information leak.

What you are able to detect and supposed to work with is entering/existing full screen mode state changes, via the `mozfullscreenchange` event. See the [Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Does that means, the only way to make the dialog(maybe something else)'Press ESC to exit fullscreen, allow fullscreen, allow, reject' disappear is user clicked button, otherwise the dialog exist all the time? In other words, How can I make the dialog fade out? with javascript pr something else?